# What does the "-0700" part mean in the result for 'git log'?

Tags: git, github

What does the '-0700' mean in these typical result for 'git log '

$ git log

commit cccc64de3947828f487a8ce3c3e72b0f68dc88c3

Author: none

Date:   Fri May 20 05:54:45 2011 -0700

I tried but [None](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) - [of](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) - [these](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) documentations explains it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the date displayed is UTC - 7 hours (or Pacific Daylight Time (PDT))

In other words, the UTC (GMT) date is

```
Fri May 20 05:54:45 2011 + 7 hours

=

Fri May 20 12:54:45 2011 UTC  (12:54pm)
```

[More information on time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone)